# fetch whole data from a database table in to solr

Tags: mysql, solr

i want to fetch all data( all rows and columns) of a table from MySQL database to solr. how can i achieve this.currently i am able to fetch specific columns from the database table. my db-data-config.xml is:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.9:3306/angara" user="root" password="ampliflex" />
    <document>
         <entity name="tdiamonds" query="select UID_PK, ProductUID, name, price,Weight from tdiamonds">

            <field column="UID_PK" name="id"/>
            <field column="ProductUID" name="product_uid"/>
            <field column="name" name="dname"/>
            <field column="price" name="dprice"/>
            <field column="Weight" name="dweight"/>

          </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

now i want to know what query syntax i should use so that i can fetch all data or is it really possible??

Answer (score 0):

Try `SELECT * FROM tdiamonds` as the query and add a [dynamicField](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Dynamic_fields) `'*'` in schema.xml